# How to download a cloud deployed APIFunction including dependent definitions?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

I want to download a cloud `APIFunction`, but I don't get dependent functions back.

I tried deploying this function

```
f[] := "hello ";
g[] := "world!";
o = CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{}, f[] <> g[] &]];
URLExecute[o]
"hello world!"
```

But when I download the `CloudObject` I only get the definition for the `APIFunction`, but I am missing definitions for `g` and `f`.

```
CloudGet[o]
APIFunction[{}, f[] <> g[] &]
```

Comment: They are read too. If you want to see them try `Import[o, "Text"]`